# How to use translation __() with hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, jsx

While creating a block in WordPress, I'll need to add a translation with a link inside. I'm doing this way in JS, but it isn't providing expected results:

```
import { render } from '@wordpress/element';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

export default function Final() {

    let d = <a href="https://example.com">bothered me.</a>;

    return (

        <p>  { __( 'The cold never {d} anyway.', 'text-domain' ) } </p>

    )
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    const appRoot = document.getElementById( 'root' );

    if ( appRoot ) {
        render(
            <Final/>,
            appRoot
        )
    }
});
```

In PHP, I could easily do that with sprintf and using placeholder like %1s.

```
echo sprintf(
    __( 'The cold never %1s anyway', 'text-domain' ),
    '<a href="https://example.com">bothered me.</a>'
);
```

How do I do the equivalent of sprintf when creating a block in react?

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to insert a html tag inside a translated sentence using React. You will need to keep a placeholder (something like `{0}`) and then you will need to replace it with the actual component.

*When with PHP you are simply replacing text with other text (that is your HTML), in react you are using components so you can not simply replace them.*

```
export default function Final() {
    const [before, after] = __('The cold never {0} anyway.', 'text-domain').split('{0}');
    
    return (<p>
        { before }
        <a href="https://example.com">bothered me.</a>
        { after }
    </p>);
}
```

#### Side note

This `'The cold never {d} anyway.'` is a plain string, maybe you intended `` `The cold never ${d} anyway.` `` (for string templating).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use template strings(ES6):

```
export default function Final() {

    let d = <a href="https://example.com">bothered me.</a>;

    return (

        <p>  { __( `The cold never ${d} anyway.`, 'text-domain' ) } </p>

    )
}
```

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `sprintf` built-in with `@wordpress/i18n`

```js
import { render } from '@wordpress/element';
import { sprintf, __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

export default function Final() {
    let d = '<a href="https://example.com">bothered me.</a>';
    let txt = sprintf(__('The cold never %1s anyway.', 'text-domain'), d);
    return (
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: txt }}></p>
    )
}
```